# double conditions in if statement

Tags: javascript, if-statement, google-apps-script, google-sheets

as I'm not that good in coding i have a small issue in my code that i need to find a solution for it. my code bellow that i made is to transfer data from one sheet to another one based on value on a specific cell, that it's working perfectly, but for another case that i have i need to make double conditions for my if statement that they need to be both of them true so it can work, first condition it's the one that i already made, and the second one is i want to check if the cell number 12 is not empty.

```
for (i = 1; i < dataValues.length; i++) {
    if (dataValues[i][11] === 'COMMANDE CONFIRMER' && ) {
        pasteSheet.appendRow([dataValues[i][0],
            dataValues[i][1],
            dataValues[i][2],
            dataValues[i][3],
            dataValues[i][4],
            dataValues[i][5],
            dataValues[i][6],
            dataValues[i][7],
            dataValues[i][8],
            dataValues[i][9],
            dataValues[i][10],
            dataValues[i][11]]);

        var clearRow = i + 2;
        copySheet.getRange('A' + clearRow + ':L' + clearRow).clearContent();
    }
}
```

Comment: About `the second one is i want to check if the cell number 12 is not empty`, in this case, I think that it is required to know the range of values of `dataValues`. For example, if the 1st column of values of `dataValues` is the column "A", `if the cell number 12 is not empty` is `dataValues[i][11].toString() != ""`. But, if you use this condition, I would like to recommend to add it to the 1st condition like `if (dataValues[i][11].toString() != "" && dataValues[i][11] === 'COMMANDE CONFIRMER') {`. But, I cannot understand your whole script. So, if this was not useful, I apologize.

Comment: if (dataValues[i][11] === 'COMMANDE CONFIRMER' && dataValues[i][12].toString() != ""). is this can work ? the if statement i have i want double conditions in it, to check if cell 11 have that value and also to check on cell12 if it's not empty

Answer (score 0):

#### Column L is probably [i][11]

Based up what you added in the comment below I'd say that this is probably what you are after.

`if (dataValues[i][11] === 'COMMANDE CONFIRMER' &&  dataValues[i][12]) {`  so then all you need is to make sure it's not empty.  Or  it's also possible that you not really sure what you want so let us know.

Comment: I'm not sure if it will be full or no, that's why i want the script to check it. i want the cell 11 to be the exact value that I'm referring there,and the cell12 to not be empty

Comment: I assume that the first column of the data range for dataValues was column A so that means that [=[i][11] is column 12.  So my question is to know if you actually mean column 12 or some other column.  Columns are usually 1 larger that the index numbers for data arrays when the first column of the data range is column 1.  I'm only asking you this because you described yourself as someone who is weak in programming.

Comment: i'm not sure if i got you right, but what i want is to have 2 conditions on if statement on the cells L and M, L to have that exact value, and M to not be empty

Comment: Can you provide the definition of dataValues?

Comment: if (dataValues[i][11] === 'COMMANDE CONFIRMER' && dataValues[i][12].toString() != "").  it needs to be something like this,

Comment: @IMADLAKH Not really dataValues[i][12] can be either falsy or truthy check it out in your favorite Javascript reference